# Delete all JournalContent versions programmatically

Tags: api, liferay, liferay-6

I need to create the delete functionality to delete the contents trought my custom portlet.

I've tested the following sentences but all of them, delete the latest version of the content, but the rest still there.

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), article.getArticleId(), sc);
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteJournalArticle(article);
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(article);
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(article, SLASH, sc);
JournalArticleServiceUtil.deleteArticle(themeDisplay.getCompanyGroupId(), article.getArticleId(), SLASH, sc);
```

Is there any method in Liferay API to delete all the versions or I have to loop over the version and delete it one by one?

Comment: Have you tried  `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(
   long groupId, String articleId, ServiceContext serviceContext)`, based on method comments in source file, it seems this method deletes all resources related to article.?

Comment: Yeah Pankajkumar,, i've tried it. In fact, is the first example i posted, but delete the lastest version only

Comment: First example you posted have first parameter as companyId, but this method has groupId. Have you passed companyId by mistake?

Comment: Sorry, i was testing with differents Id's,this is the last example.

Comment: As @PankajkumarKathiriya said, if you saw the api, that one should fit your needs. ** deleteArticle(long groupId, String articleId, ServiceContext serviceContext) ** Maybe you're using a different groupId? Try with themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() to retrieve the groupId  https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.3-ga4/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/impl/JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with this code:

```
List<JournalArticle> versiones=JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticles(groupId, articleId);
for (int j = 0; j < versiones.size(); j++) {
   JournalArticle version=versiones.get(j);
   JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(groupId, version.getArticleId(), version.getVersion(), null,null)
}
```

Comment: I thought this solution too, but i supposed that it should exists a method in the API to delete all version.